# How to create Katalon studio generating automatic test cases using AI

Tags: katalon-studio

How to create Katalon studio generating automatic test cases using AI.

i hava a dought Record web is also generating automatic test cases so it is AI. incase both are different how to dowload and how to configure write small example.